# React Native: React Navigation StackNavigator not working. Getting error: “undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.props.navigation.navigate')”

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm facing one issue I have simple and usual navigation flow with `Stacknavigation` and once they login they will see the Tab navigation.

In tab navigation I have chat screen which will render segments in one screen, each segment will produce a list of chat heads which is supposed to be open in the individual chat screen.

```
Chatscreen.js
```

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { 
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet
    } from "react-native";
import AdminChat from './Chat/AdminChat';
import AcademicChat from './Chat/AcademicChat';
import ActiveChat from './Chat/ActiveChat';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Button, Container, Content, Header, Body, Left, Right, Title } from 'native-base';

class ChatScreen extends Component{
    
    state = {
      activeIndex : 0
    }

    segmentClicked = (index) => {
      this.setState({activeIndex: index})
    }

    renderSection = () => {
      if (this.state.activeIndex === 0) {
        return <AdminChat />
      } else if (this.state.activeIndex === 1) {
        return <AcademicChat />
      } else {
        return <ActiveChat />
      }
    }

    render(){
        return (
          <Container>
            <Header style={{backgroundColor: '#8E44AD'}}>
                <Left>
                </Left>
                <Body>
                    <Title style={{color: 'white'}}>Chat</Title>
                </Body>
                <Right />
                </Header>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'grey' }}>
                  <Button 
                    transparent
                    onPress={()=>{this.segmentClicked(0)}}
                    active={this.state.activeIndex === 0}>
                    <Text style={[this.state.activeIndex === 0 ? { color: '#8E44AD' } : {color: 'grey'}]}>Admin</Text>
                  </Button>
                  <Button 
                    transparent
                    onPress={()=>{this.segmentClicked(1)}}
                    active={this.state.activeIndex === 1}>
                    <Text style={[this.state.activeIndex === 1 ? { color: '#8E44AD' } : {color: 'grey'}]}>Academic</Text>
                  </Button>
                  <Button 
                    transparent
                    onPress={()=>{this.segmentClicked(2)}}
                    active={this.state.activeIndex === 2}>
                    <Text style={[this.state.activeIndex === 2 ? { color: '#8E44AD' } : {color: 'grey'}]}>Chat</Text>
                  </Button>
                </View>
                {this.renderSection()}                
            </View>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
export default ChatScreen;
```

from above code, I have generated Chat Screen, which is a part of tab navigator, and in that I am loading the AdminScreen.js.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";
import axios from 'axios';

class AdminChat extends Component{
    state = {
        adminChat : [],
        userid: "2980",
        usertype: '1'
      }
      
      componentWillMount = async () => {
          console.log(this.state.userid)
          try {
            let { data } = await axios
              .post("https://tgesconnect.org/api/Communication_group", {
                userid: this.state.userid,
                group_id: '0',
                is_sub_group: '0',
                usertype: this.state.usertype,
              })
              .then(response => {
                //console.log(response.data.data.group_list);
                if (response.data.status === "success") {
                  //console.log("Success")
                  this.setState({
                    adminChat: response.data.data.group_list,
                  });
                } else {
                  alert("Something went wrong");
                }
              });
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          //console.log(this.state.adminChat.group_name[0])
        };
      
        renderSeparator = () => {
              return (
                <View
                  style={{
                    height: 1,
                    width: "100%",
                    backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
                  }}
                />
              );
        };
      
        render () {
          return (
              <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
              <FlatList
                data={this.state.adminChat}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <ListItem
                    // roundAvatar
                    title={item.group_name}
                    // subtitle={item.email}
                    // avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
                    containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
                    onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.push('onescreen')}
                  />
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item.group_id}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
               
              />
            </List>
          )
        }
}
export default AdminChat;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center'
    }
});
```

Now if I click to open a single List item and use this.props.navigation.navigate('adminSingle.js') it is not working, how can I solve it?

I am using "react-navigation": "^2.6.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to pass navigation as prop for `AdminScreen`

```
renderSection = () => {
  if (this.state.activeIndex === 0) {
    return <AdminChat navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
  } else if (this.state.activeIndex === 1) {
    return <AcademicChat />
  } else {
    return <ActiveChat />
  }
}
```